# WPF format DateTime in TextBlock?

Tags: wpf, formatting, textblock

I have a `TextBlock` that is bound to a `DateTime` property. How do I configure the format of the date?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

There is a string format property available when you are declaring the binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DateTimeValue, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" />
```

(You need to be on .NET 3.5 SP1 for this property to exist)

Comment: Just letting you know this is now TextBox <- capital B

Answer (score 39):

If you want to use a **common format string** between bindings, you could declare the binding like this:

```
<Textbox Text={Binding Path=DateTimeValue, StringFormat={x:Static local:Constants.DateTimeUiFormat}} />
```

With your constants class like this:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string DateTimeUiFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    //etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian! I used this in combination with `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` to get an i18n short date.

Answer (score 29):

May be helpful to someone:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now},
           StringFormat='{}{0: Today is dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy, hh:mm:ss}'}"/>
```

or 24h and 2digits month and year format:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now},
           StringFormat='{}{0: Today is dddd, MM.dd.yy, HH:mm:ss}'}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateTimeValue, StringFormat='Today is {0: dd/MM/yyyy}'}" />
```