# How to make a DateTime Property binded TextBox read a date in dd-mm-yyyy format in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBox in WPF binded to a DateTime property. Whenever a user enter a date in that TextBox, i need the binded DateTime property to read the date in dd-MM-yyyy format.

i.e when the user enter 05-04-2015, the binded DateTime Property should get DateTime value corresponding to 5th April 2015.

I did a normal binding but the property is interpreting the date as 4th May 2015 instead of 5th April 2015.

In View:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" 
     Text="{Binding NewStaff.Insurance.ExpiryDate}"></TextBox>
```

In viewmodel I have a NewStaff property which refer to a Staff class instance, this staff class has a insurance class instance. Inside Insurance class I have a DateTime Property called ExpiryDate.

```
class Staff{

    public ICard Insurance{get;set;}

    public Staff(){

        Insurance = new Insurance();
    }

}

class Insurance:ICard
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Expiry date of insurance card.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime ExpiryDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
 }
```

Now when I type 05-04-2015 in the textbox, the binded ExpiryDate property is interpreting the date as 4th May 2015. Whereas I need ExpiryDate to interpret it as 5th April 2015.

Comment: Duplicate of this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333052/wpf-format-datetime-in-textblock

Comment: @LeZohan68, this is a WPF question, *not* a web related question.

Comment: Sorry it is not the duplicate of that question. I already referred that. Using string format will only change the date i entered into the specified format. i.e when i type 05-04-2015, and if i use stringformat then my textbox will display the date as 04-05-2015.

Comment: why dont you use the DatePicker?  thats what its for and eliminates confusion about formats

Comment: I need to use this technique for converting hijri date to georgian date. will DatePicker allow dates to be read in hijri date format?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570197/ASP-NET-DatePicker-User-Control-Hijri-Gregorian-Sh)  
can help you. That's a Datepicker which lets you choose the calendar type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`DateTime.ParseExact` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) in your data bound property setter, or in an `IValueConverter.Convert` method. This will enable you to parse the correct `DateTime` value using your required format. See this example from the linked page on MSDN:

```
  string dateString, format;  
  DateTime result;
  CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

  // Parse date-only value with invariant culture.
  dateString = "06/15/2008";
  format = "d";
  try {
     result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
     Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
  }
  catch (FormatException) {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
  }
```