# Converting Date to English Date

Tags: c#, xaml

I've just started using C#. I'm trying to create a static method that takes a string as such; `2018-03-15T08:50:00-05:00` and converts it to `Mar 3, 2018`. I've researched this for a long time but none of the questions seem to convert to this format, rather all of the answers convert to `dd-mm-yyyy`.

I think it would be something like this:

```
public static string ToProperDate(this string input)
    {
       return String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", input);
    }
```

Could someone please help me? Thank-you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF format DateTime in TextBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333052/wpf-format-datetime-in-textblock)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should parse the text to a `DateTime` first to ease formatting it.

So change the input to a `DateTime` instance:

```
public static string ToProperDate(this DateTime input)
{
   return String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", input);
}
```

Or parse it in your method:

```
public static string ToProperDate(this string input)
{
   DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(input);

   return String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", d);
}
```

Comment: or `public static string ToProperDate(this DateTime input) => string.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", input);` :)

Comment: That is the same as my answer @aloisdg

Comment: Will DateTime.Parse treat ISO 6801 string representation independent of the current culture? I know that's true for SQL Server, but is it true for .Net as well?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is one of the default conversion formats.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Good to know!, as it turns out, it's documented in the remarks section, under the title **Parsing and cultural conventions** - All overloads of the Parse method are culture-sensitive unless the string to be parsed conforms to the ISO 8601 pattern.